# Images are stacked on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create two columns. One column is on the left and the other column is on the right. These two columns have an image and text to go along with it. Instead of having each image and text turn into a block of its own on a separate line, the images and text stack up on top of each other for both columns. How can I solve this?

PHP/HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"?parameter="3"/>
    </head>

    <?php
        $resultSet = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Articles");

        if ($resultSet->num_rows != 0)
        {
           while ($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
           {
            $id = $rows["id"];
            $images = $rows["image"];
            $text = $rows["text"];

            echo "<div id=body>";
            if ($id > 3 && $id < 8)
            {
                echo "<div id=left>";
                echo "<img src=$images>";
                echo "<p>$text</p>";
                echo "</div>";  
            }

            if ($id > 8)
            {
                echo "<div id=right>";
                echo "<img src=$images>";
                echo "<p>$text</p>";
                echo "</div>";  
            }
            echo "</div>";  
           }
        }
 ?>
```

CSS

```
#body{
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
    height: auto;
}

#left{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    width: 28.33%;
    display: block;

}

#left img{
    width: 100%;
}

#right{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0%;
    width: 28.33%;

}

#right img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: One comment, a side note if you will, you will likely not want to use `id` because `id` values are meant to be unique. Use `class` instead.

Comment: As for stacking, it might be the `absolute` setting for `position` that is stacking the images.

Comment: @Rasclatt It is because of position: absolute, but the reason why I use position absolute is because if I use position: relative, the right column will go underneath the left column

Comment: You may want to try doing `<ul><li></li></ul>` and displaying them as table cells. That should set them into two columns.

Comment: @Rasclatt I tried doing float: left and float: right, and it is doing the trick, but for some reason it's making the images next to each other instead of each image on a separate line

Answer (score 0):

1.) Add singular ' quotes around you attribute values in the echo statements.
`echo "<img src='path-to-img'>";`

2.) If its only 2 columns, then the css for  left box should be

```
 `{position:relative; float:left;width:50%} ,
  {position:relative; float:right;width:50%}`
```

for right box. From there you can choose to absolute position the images or text-align:center the boxes or whatever you want from there.

3.) Naming a `id='body'` is bad practice, you should rename it.

4.) Set CSS to `display:block` for both, not just one of those divs (left/right)

Comment: The images are on their separate lines, but for the right column it starts out on the same line as the last image for the left column. I want the right column to start out at the same line as the first image of the left column

Comment: @bytes sorry, im on mobile right now, so i cant show you in code the errors, but you have several css problems causing this.

Comment: Could you tell me how I can make my right column start on the same line as my left column?

Comment: This is showing the first image and second image next to each other, the third and fourth next to each other and so on. Also, whenever I alter the width to less than 50%, it shows every image on the same line

Comment: I want to have them less than 50%, so I can add another column in between for a total of 3 columns

Comment: @bytes you didnt mention a third column in your post, which changes things. Also, there seems to be other CSS involved in this. Lastly, im on mobile phone so ive reached the limit of what i can do from here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First off there are a lot of things are added that don't need to be. That said, try this:

```
#left{
  width: 28.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;

}

#right{
  width: 28.33%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: This is putting the images next to each other instead of having them each on their separate lines

Comment: You need to be more specific then. I misunderstood what you want. What is it exactly that you are looking to do?

Comment: I am trying to create a three column page. The left column has an image on one line and then a text relating to that image on the next line (The image is on top of the text). The right column is the same as the left column just with different images and texts. The middle column contains an image and then a text NEXT to the image, this is the difference between the middle column and both other columns. But I have no idea how to accomplish this, I was trying to do absolute positioning and then set the top to 0%, but this only stacks the images and texts on top of each other